I get an error that says "Object of type Message is not JSON serializable" when I run this code
Whenever I run this code, I get an error that says "Object of type Message is not JSON serializable". The code is supposed to create a chatbot to the local host. There is an API key involved and this code is based off of a tutorial video.
import chainlit as cl
import openai
import os

os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY'] = 'random API key'

openai.api_key = 'random API key'

@cl.on_message
async def main(message : str):
    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model = 'gpt-4-1106-preview',
        messages = [
            {"role": "assistant", "content": "you are an assistant that is obsessed with legos"},
            {"role": "user", "content":message}
        ],
        temperature = 1,
    
    )
    await cl.Message(content =f" {response['choices'][0]['message']['content']}",).send()

I tried importing JSON and such, but that didn't work. I am trying to get the chatbot to reply to the user with a message. However, I still ended up getting the same error message as previously stated.

The error indicates that your message parameter is not actually a str, but rather a cl.Message. Check out the chainlit docs to see how to use a Message object. You probably want message.content.

@cl.on_message
async def main(message: cl.Message):
    try:
        response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
            model='gpt-4-1106-preview',
            messages=[
                {"role": "assistant", "content": "you are an assistant that is obsessed with legos"},
                {"role": "user", "content": message.content}  # Use message.content
            ],
            temperature=1,
        )
        
        # Get the assistant's reply
        reply = response['choices'][0]['message']['content']
        
        # Send the reply back to the user
        await cl.Message(content=reply).send()
    
    except Exception as e:
        await cl.Message(content=f"An error occurred: {str(e)}").send()


Right idea, wrong formatting and missing explanation.
